# How to add multi language option in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, localization, flashdevelop, localizable.strings

I am trying to add an option where i can have the flash fonts show up in different languages when i choose from a drop down list , i found a sample here -

http://www.girlsgogames.com/game/shopaholic_hollywood.html

If you look  there is a language drop down with country flags , is there any way of achieving this , are there any tools that can do it for us ...

I tried with xml but failed miserably as the tutorials i just could not understand ...

Kindly guide in this regard or point to some tutorial , i want a combo box like here to choose language from ...

I tried and searched but could not found any such tool that can actually convert stuff in the file for flash ...

Thanks in advance ...

Regards

Comment: is this a question about how to make your flash support multiple languages or how to make a "combo-box" like element?

Comment: @MartonPallgi - thanks a lot for the time , its about making flash support multiple languages like the way one sees  in the sample link .. to convert all the fonts to language as selected by user from combo box ...

Comment: The question is a bit too broad as is, but maybe i can give you some pointers. The combo box is pretty straightforward, you can even make it in the flash cs if you want to. Just make a box with some buttons. For the language part, you should store all text in a static class, store the current language as a static var, and make getters so that ie `myTexts.text1` returns a string depending on the current language selected.

Comment: @MartonPallagi - thanks a lot , as i have not worked with classes , can you please point me to a language translation module , i will try my best to do it ..

Comment: oh there is no language translation module...you have to supply the alternate languages manually, and do a bit of coding to switch them on button clicks